# How to return a string in Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I want to return a string after my ajax code is executed. This is how my code looks like in my `html`:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $('#form').submit(function(event){
            var formData = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/transform",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data){
                    data
                },
            });     
        });
    });(jQuery);
</script>
```

Basically what I want is to desplay the string that the method`/transform` will return once it finished, something like "Done!", I want to see this message in `localhost:5000`, not in the console.

To execute my code I access to `localhost:5000`, however, when the message returned by `/transform` is displayed the url is `localhost:5000/transform` what makes me think ajax is not working.

For what I have read, by using Ajax my code is being executed asynchronously, therefore it can't automatically access to the return of `/transform`. I have read about callbacks but still I don't get how can I use it, I am very new to this (I started yesterday and it is my first time using both html and js).

I also checked this question and answer [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but still I can't see how can insert in my code the callback they are talking about.

Is there a way to do it?

This is the html I am using:

```
<html>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" >        
                    <div class="panel-heading">

                        <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align:center">Select a file</h3>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="data_file" />
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="submit"/>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can just replace `data` inside the `success` callback with `console.log(data)` if you just want to see the response in the console. Also the `;` before `(jQuery)` will cause a syntax error, so you should remove that.

Comment: I want to see it in the browser, so ``console.log(data)`` won't work for me.

Comment: You'll have to update the DOM to do this inside your success function, e.g. `$('h1').text(data.valueYouWantToAdd)` or something like this. We'd have to see your HTML to help with the selector. Plus, it would be helpful if you also mentioned where you and what you would like displayed.

Comment: @Marisa You see console.log output in your dev tools in the browser (F12 in most browser) - really handy for debugging. You'll also see if your pages reloads there, in the network tab (if you are using chrome)

Comment: @TimRooke I updated my question with what you asked.

Comment: @Marisa As an example you could have: ```success: function(data) {
                    $('.panel-title').text('This is a string!');
                }```. This would select the element with a class of `panel-title` in your HTML and set its text value to `'This is a string!'`, but you could pass it any string,

Comment: @TimRooke isn't there a way to access the data given by ``/transform`` (a string) and write this string, instead of writing a specific one?

Comment: @Marisa Try: `success: function(data) { $('.panel-title').text(JSON.stringify(data)); }`

Comment: @TimRooke it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like Robin Zigmond commented, you have an syntax error in your script, which prevents it from working. So your concerns if your script is beeing executed were right. The last line of your script should look like this

```
})(jQuery);
```

(semicolon removed between closing and opening paranthesis)

You'll note such things in your developer console (F12 in most browser), as I already mentioned in the comments. You will also see console.log output there, which is really handy for debugging javascript.

Secondly, in order to display your response, you can do something like this

```
success: function(data) { 
    $('#form').prepend( "<p>" + data + "</p>" );
}
```

Comment: if I delete the ``;`` the submit bottom is not redirecting me to the transform method. I have no clue why.

Comment: @Marisa That's because you added event.preventDefault(), which prevents the form from actually beeing submitted (causing the browser to reload).

Comment: I am working now, but shouldn't I close the connection of the event?

Comment: @Marisa I'm not sure which connection you mean. If you refer to the connection of the request, then you don't need to worry about anything as your browser manages the actuall connection for you.

Comment: I tried to do it as you suggest but still I am seeing in the webpage the url (``localhost:5000/transform``) instead of just ``localhost:5000`` with the message that transform is returning.

Comment: No, everything is executed correctly and the program does what it is expected to do with the exception of that...

Comment: where did you put your javascript? At the bottom of your page or in your header?

Comment: At the bottom, after </body> and </html>.

Comment: That's definitely an invalid position as nothing is allowed outside the html tags. Try placing it BEFORE your closing body-tag. I don't think that's the problem though. Can you put your entire solution in a jsFiddle, as its really hard to guess the problem

Comment: So should it be at the bottom before the </body></html>?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my last commet. (Hit the enter key a little to early) Please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net ) of your current work?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your goals are this is probably not what you want for your long term solution, but given that you're just starting out I think it will be good to see how this works.

Assuming you are getting `data` back without any issues you can display it in the DOM using jQuery as the go-between. For example, you can add `<div id="confirmationMessage"></div>` wherever you would like to show the message in your HTML. You can then use jQuery to put the text into the DOM as follows:

```
success: function(data) { 
    $('#confirmationMessage').text(data)
}
```